# Creating a generic setter which I can use to set any property within a class

Tags: c#, .net

I know this is possible to do i am just striking a complete blank here. Basically what I want to have is the following:

```
public abstract class Object
{
     private int id;

     public virtual int Id 
     {
         get => id;
         set => Set(ref id, value)
     }

     public bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value) 
     {
         ????
     }
}
```

```
public abstract class DerivedObject : IdObject
{
     private string name;

     public string Name
     {
         get => name;
         set => Set(ref name, value);
     }
}
```

This might be a little confusing but what i want to have happen is that I want to have the option to have all classes that derive from Id Object to be able to use the `Set()` method to change the values to their properties, it has something to do with how I want to implement `IRevertibleChangeTracking` but go deeper with it.

Is there anyone who can assist me with this? Basically I need the blanks (?'s) filled in to populate the `Set()` method within the top class

EDIT: edited the Set() method to reflect Code Casters comment

Comment: What have you tried? `Set<T>(ref T field, T value)`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for the comment, i did that just now, thank you however whilst this gets me partly there i am still striking a complete blank on how to actually get the field filled with the value. ill edit the post to reflect this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errm..haven't you almost answered this yourself?  You just need to do name = value in Set now don't you?!  The code below all works fine.  I'm not sure what bool you want returned from Set, so I made it void.

```
    private void Run()
    {
        IdObject idObject = new IdObject();
        idObject.Id = 1;
        DerivedObject derivedObject = new DerivedObject();
        derivedObject.Id = 2;
        derivedObject.Name = "MyName";
    }
}

public class IdObject
{
    private int id;

    public virtual int Id
    {
        get => id;
        set => Set(ref id, value);
    }

    public void Set<T>(ref T name, T value)
    {
        name = value;
    }
}

public class DerivedObject : IdObject
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was way easier then expected, thank you very much to  both you and @CodeCaster.